# javascript compare times with miliseconds

Tags: javascript, time

I want to compare the times in the following array. Times are in miliseconds:

```
[ "00:02:03.25", "00:02:02.962", "00:02:02.675", "00:02:02.502", "00:02:03.458",
 "00:02:02.631", "00:02:02.750", "00:02:02.778", "00:02:03.200"]
```

I want to compare the times in the form of hh:mm:ss and in the case that two times are the same, they should be compared with the miliseconds.

But any idea if there will be any better way.

Thanks!

Comment: If you would not like to use external library https://jsfiddle.net/gnj315uz/

Comment: you can use moment.js compare function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ciao, I made this example to compare times and order your array:

```js
let array = [ "00:02:03.25", "00:02:02.962", "00:02:02.675", "00:02:02.502", "00:02:03.458", "00:02:02.631", "00:02:02.750", "00:02:02.778", "00:02:03.200"]

let array_ordered = array.sort(function(a, b) {
   if(moment.duration(a) < moment.duration(b)) return -1;
   else if (moment.duration(a) > moment.duration(b)) return 1;
   return 0;
})
console.log(array_ordered)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.17.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```

I used `moment.duration` to compare times, then I sorted array using `sort` function with a custom sort order.

**EDIT** @dariosicily suggested another solution that could be more efficient:

```js
let array = [ "00:02:03.25", "00:02:02.962", "00:02:02.675", "00:02:02.502", "00:02:03.458", "00:02:02.631", "00:02:02.750", "00:02:02.778", "00:02:03.200"]

    let array_ordered = array.sort(function(a, b) {
       return moment.duration(a) - moment.duration(b);
    })
    console.log(array_ordered)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.17.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Hello, your method will never return `0` , should not return `moment.duration(a) - moment.duration(b)` ?

Comment: You can directly returns just the difference without distinguish between the three cases.